# Memory leak when using tf.Model and tf.Model.fit() in a loop. clear_session() does not help [TensorFlow 2.11.0]

Tags: python, tensorflow

With TF version == 2.11.0, memory usage steadily increases when using tf.Model and tf.Model.fit() in a loop, and leads to Out Of Memory exception saturating the memory eventually. clear_session() does not help. The same code with TF version == 2.9.2 has an almost constant memory usage instead, and works as expected.

Code to reproduce:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    x = self.dense2(x)
    x = self.dense3(x)
    x = self.dense4(x)
    return x

for r in range(0, 10000):
    model = MyModel()
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.uniform((64*4, 1000)), tf.ones((64*4))))
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

    model.fit(ds.batch(64))
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    time.sleep(3)
    print("round: ", r)
```

System information:

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.16.10 x86_64)

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): source

TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.11.0

Python version: 3.10.6

Comment: I have the same problem running .fit() on a more complex model in a loop.  clear_session() doesn't help.  I am running tensorflow 2.11 in an ngc container, nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:23.02-tf2-py3, in both Windows 11 with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) and on native Ubuntu 22.04.  GPU is RTX 4070 Ti.  Python 3.8.10, Cuda 12.0.1

Comment: @Roland the code above is just a reproducible example that I have also posted on Keras's GitHub issues with no solution. Also other people acknowledged the problem. I can tell that the issue happens also with TF==2.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform garbage collection after `.predict()` with `gc.collect`.

I have the same problem with training and predicting in a loop.  My scenario is a little different bc I also have a nested loop that only does the training but at 1 epoch per iteration.  The important point is that the memory becomes filled with garbage (obsolete data) and needs to be cleaned.

Example:

```
    from gc import collect  # performs garbage collection

    for i in range(number_of_iterations):  # Walk through a test dataset
        # Build data set for training
        X_train, Y_train, X_dev, Y_dev = build_my_training_dataset()
        # Define and compile model
        model = build_my_model()
        model.compile(...)
        # Train (lstm-based) model in loop, 1 epoch at a time
        for i in range(number_of_epochs):
            model.fit(...)
            model.reset_states()

        # Make prediction on newly trained model
        yhat = model.predict()

        # Housekeeping; gc.collect() prevents memory from filling up
        clear_session()  # Clean memory of model's params
        collect()  # Garbage collection
```

Comment: Also tried that but it does not work. What version of TF are you using?

Comment: TF 2.12.0.  I am running Nvidia framework container image 23.04.  See ref. [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/support-matrix/index.html).

Comment: Are you following this general pattern?:
```
for _ in range (number):  
    model.fit()  
    model.predict()  
    clear_session()  
    gc.collect()  
```